# How do i display profile image from upload folder

Tags: backend

I've been trying to display profile image from upload folader but all i've been getting is error.... someone should please help with this as soon as possible.

```
<img src="../user/uploads/<?php echo $_FILES['passport']['name']; ?>"alt="Profile" class="rounded-circle">
```

Comment: Post the error you are getting.

Comment: No error... the picture wont just display